# Snowflake SQP-API : issue with short token expiry period

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a requirement where I need to communicate with Snowflake Sql-Api in the back-end from my application. As I come across the snowflake sql-api documentation, it supports authentication using either oauth access token or JWT token generated with keyvaluepair. For this, I am having a configuration property in my application to configure the access token with customer in properties file.

However, I see that oauth token generated has maximum expire period of 10 minutes and JWT token has maximum expire period of 60 minutes. In our use-case having the shorter expiry period is not feasible as user can't change the properties file regularly and restart my application.

I would like to know what is the way to have access token configured with long expiry period like 30/90 days etc or the way I can communicate with snowflake sql-api as per my use case.

Looking forward to hear from you.
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: For [OAuth](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-intro.html#refresh-token) you should configure the security integration to enable refresh token (OAUTH_ISSUE_REFRESH_TOKENS) to not have to regenerate the access token all the time.

Comment: @Sergiu
We can do settings for Refresh token but oauth access token expires in 10 minutes. To regenerate access token using refresh token we need client key, client secret etc.

So, I am looking for a solution where customer can configure the token in my application properties file such that it can used for longer period say 30 days. Configuring the access for every 10 minutes and restarting the application does not make sense.

Comment: @Anil did you get something on this, I am also facing same issue